# Creating months constant in JS

Tags: javascript

I need to create a constant containing the string 'JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC'

My code so far is working up to the alert stage;

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
MONTHS = 'JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC'; //months

var dateString = prompt('Enter your birth date in the form dd mmm yyyy','26 APR 1988'); //get        users date of birth
var substrings = dateString.split('');
var day = substrings[0];
var month = substrings[1];
var year = substrings[2];

var pos = months.indexOf(month);
if (pos >= 0) {
```

}

```
alert(months.indexOf(month));
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<html>
```

It works fine when I replace the
    'JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC'
with;
    var months = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT",
    "NOV", "DEC"];
So am I doing something wrong when creating the constant?

Comment: Why do you want it in that weird way? In JS there are arrays available. Btw, you haven't explained what's wrong with your string-based implementation. "My code so far is working up to the alert stage" --- it works. So? What then? How do you know it really does what you think it should do?

Comment: It would be good to start by trying to work out what is going on. Are the numbers alerted related or not?

Comment: I think that's the way I've been asked to do it (using constants): Create and appropriately name constants to store the following value: 
A string containing month abbreviations 'JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC'

Answer (score 1):

Your first `MONTHS` var is a string, so when you use string.indexOf you will get the position of what you are searching compared with all string content. Take this example :

```
var str = "JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC";
console.log(str.indexOf("JUN")) ;      //   gives 15 !!
```

With your second `months` var wich is an array, this time :

```
console.log(months.indexOf("JUN")) ;      //   gives 5, good value because arrays starts always with index 0, you have to do 5 + 1 or add an empty cell at the first of your months array
```

I hope that's more clear now for you.

Answer (score 0):

You defined "MONTHS" and then tried to use "months" later in your code.  JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Your split should have specified a break on a blank:

```
var substrings = dateString.split(' ');
```